# How do I print the name of the Section on an index page

Tags: templating

I have an `index page` for articles in a `section`.  Call the section "dogs."

**How do I template to output the name of the `section`?**  This is `not` an entry, but an index page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ craft.app.getSections().getSectionByHandle('dogs').name }}
```